# How to bind and call method of c# obejct in React component class

Tags: c#, reactjs, cefsharp

I am having a Cefsharp container in which I am loading a react app hosted on my local node server. I have regeisterd a c# object in my .net project as shown below:-

```
browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("bound", new Client(), isAsync: true, options: BindingOptions.DefaultBinder);
```

now in one of my react component class I want to refer a method of that C# object. What I am doing is I am trying to access that using

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.invoke();
  }

  async invoke() {
    const message = await window.bound.message();
    this.setState({selectedItem: message});
  }
```

And here is my C# object:-

```
public class Client
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Message()
        {
            return "ClientABCD";
        }
    }
```

But this is not working. I am getting "bound is not defined error". I have gone through dozens of articles but most of them are referring to CefSharp library in their HTML file which is part of their .Net project. But in my case I don't have any HTML file nor I have any CefSharp library at react side. Does 'bound' gets bind with window object in javascript? Please suggest.

Comment: Please read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript If you are developing a new app then you should be using `isAsync: true` when registering an object as the non async version is no longer being developed.

Comment: @amaitland I have gone through this article.The article suggest that I need to await on CefSharp.BindObjectAsync() after binding registering c# object as isAsync: true. But Cefsharp reference is not there in my node project. Do I need to refer that cauz it's throwing the same error.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried

Comment: I have cracked this one. We have to execute CefSharp.BindObjectAsync('boundAsync') from C# code itself using ExecuteJavaScriptAsync api and then access exposed object in React app. Thanks @amaitland for your time and attention.